# Is it possible to use a Multipatch to implement IFeatureRenderer.Draw in a custom renderer

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcscene

I have a custom renderer which need to render modified geometry.  The input features are all coming in via the `IFeatureCursor` as polygon elements.   (This is similar to [this example](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/doc/881b6264-f6c5-4ffd-b613-7ff4c3961564.htm), though I'm not rendering points.)

I can easily render Polygons, Lines, and Points via either passing the new geometry into `IFeatureDraw.Draw` or calling `IDisplay.DrawPolygon`/`IDisplay.DrawPoint`/etc.

However, `IDisplay` does not provide a mechanism for drawing a multipatch, and passing this in as the geometry to `IFeatureDraw.Draw` results in nothing drawn to the screen.

Is there a way to directly "draw" a multipatch element (preferrably with texturing), within this method?

Comment: Is this in 2D Display (ArcMap) or in ArcScene or Globe?

Comment: @Craig: This needs to be supported in all three, though I'm willing to use multiple code paths to handle it.  This is for a plugin data source, so the support will need to be "global.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Craig says, OpenGL is the way to go for 3D.

See [Creating an ArcGIS Engine Application With C-Sharp and OpenGL](http://www.scribd.com/doc/53602634/Creating-an-ArcGIS-Engine-Application-With-C-Sharp-and-OpenGL).  Earlier versions of ArcGIS Explorer also [supported OpenGL calls](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/explorer/CustomDrawing.html), but last time I checked Esri no longer supports it.

I don't know why they did this - OpenGL drawing really helped differentiate AGX from Google Earth.

**Update**

Even if your plugin returned multipatches correctly, I don't think ArcObjects offers methods to support drawing multipatches with OpenGL calls.  It would likely be easier to just draw from their native format (by-pass the plugin in other words). I've never used it, but here's a [script that shows how to use OpenGL with ArcScene](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=13983).

Answer (score 1):

2D display (IDisplay) does not support drawing multipatches directly.  You'll need to covert them to footprints (see IMultipatch::XYFootprint for how to extract the footprint).  If you want a 2D rendering of the multipatch textures you'll need to create an image from a 2D projection of the multipatch and draw that.

For 3D, you should be able to just return mulitpatches in the cursor and it will work but honestly most people just implement a custom layer for globe and do their own work in OpenGL.

Comment: I'm trying to support ArcScene primarily (not Globe), but also map/globe as secondary.  Unfortunately, returning multipatches in the cursor doesn't work in a plugin dataset properly, from what I can tell...